# Swift segue performed multiple times

Tags: swift, segue

A segue in my app is being called multiple times, which is causing the view to continuously "load" until the app stops calling the segue function. It does this about 4 times until it's finished. After placing breakpoints in the code I noticed that the app is bouncing between these two functions:

```
if success {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("startGame", sender: "user")
}
```

That is the action that triggers the segue (the user swipes something). It then goes to the next breakpoint:

```
if (segue.identifier == "startGame") {
    let destinationNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController
     destinationNavigationController.user = self.users[self.currentUser]
 }
```

The app goes back and forth between the two sections about 4 times. When I created the segue in my storyboard I made sure to wire the segue from the view controller itself (not a table/UI view) to the destination view.

What else can I do to fix this?

Thanks![image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. In storyboard, create a segue by holding control and dragging from the yellow icon of the 1st view controller to the 2nd view controller.
2. Give it an id, and the kind should be `push` if they are embedded in a navigation controller.
3. In your 1st view controller class:

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "startGame" {
       let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController
       // this next view controller should have property that will store passed value
       viewController.user = self.users[self.currentUser]
   }
   ```

   }
4. When you want to move to the next view controller:

   ```
   performSegueWithIdentifier("startGame", sender: self)
   ```

Comment: How is this different than the code that @james provided?